# Comparación de Fechas en Java

Tags: java

como puedo comparar fechas tipo Date en este formato "yyyy-mm-dd", si ambas son tipo date, no puedo usar los operadores mayor que y menor que,

```
String fechaI1 = "2015-01-01";
String fechaF2 = "2015-02-01";

SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date fecha1 = formato.parse(fechaI1);
Date fecha2 = formato.parse(fechaF2);

if(fecha1 >= fecha2){
   System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es mayor o igual a fecha2" );
}else{
   System.out.println( "Fecha2 es menor que fecha1");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intenta utilizando los métodos `equals`, `before` o `after`, para realizar la comparación de las fechas.

Los if de tu codigo:

```
if(fecha1 >= fecha2){
   System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es mayor o igual a fecha2" );
}else{
   System.out.println( "Fecha2 es menor que fecha1");
}
```

puedes cambiarlos a:

```
 if(fecha1.equals(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es igual a fecha2" );
 }else if(fecha1.after(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es mayor a fecha2" );
 }else if(fecha1.before(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es menor a fecha2" );
 }
```

Espero esto pueda ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a la repuesta de Jesus. A partir de java 8, el JDK trae un nuevo paquete para administrar las fechas de manera mas sencilla.

Se encuentran en el paquete java.time y nos provee de clases en las que podemos manejar separadamente las fechas y las horas.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como se resolvería tu problema con el API de java.time:

```
String fechaI1 = "2015-01-01";
String fechaF2 = "2015-02-01";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

LocalDate fecha1 = LocalDate.parse(fechaI1, formatter);
LocalDate fecha2 = LocalDate.parse(fechaF2, formatter);

if(fecha1.isEqual(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es igual a fecha2" );
}else if(fecha1.isAfter(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es mayor a fecha2");
}else if(fecha1.isBefore(fecha2)){
    System.out.println( "Fecha 1 es menor a fecha2");
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.